# WPF TreeView - Set Color of text based symbol

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, treeview

I'm having issues setting some "prefix" text background and foreground colors in a tree view...  The following code sets the correct "symbol" but does not change the colors...

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ChainItem}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Symbol}" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="10" Background="{Binding Path=SymbolBackground}" Foreground="{Binding Path=SymbolBrush}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="16"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Interestingly, if an item with the above data template is selected, the "Symbol" part is black while the rest is white.  If I remove the Foreground and Background bindings, then all of the selection is white.  If I manually set the colors instead of using bindings, I get the same effect, so I am fairly certain it is not a problem with my binding, but my approach.

I know I can resolve this by using images, but I have been asked to use the text as it can change (the Symbol is actually a 3 character string).  I'm considering drawing the text on a bitmap and setting the colors, but I think there is an easier approach.

Comment: i don't understand what is not working fine. Do you mean to say that the Background and Foreground colors are not set on the symbol textbox?

Comment: correct - the symbol is the same color of the rest of the text unless selected in which the symbol text is black no matter what colors are set.

Comment: What is SymbolBrush? Please provide a MCVE when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I thought that was obvious AND I explained it in my description - replace the bindings with a color and you get the exact same effect - so replace "Background="{Binding Path=SymbolBackground}" Foreground="{Binding Path=SymbolBrush}" with "Background="Yellow" Foreground="Blue" and you get the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I was using the wrong namespace...

I was using System.Drawing and I needed System.Windows.Media